# Button does not get clicked on the first attempt

Tags: android

There are a few buttons in my activity which do not get clicked on the first attempt but they get clicked from the second time onwards. It seems that the button gets focus on the first click and gets actually pressed from the second time onwards. What can be the reason that these buttons do not get clicked the first time? 
I have noticed that this behaviour is only shown by buttons that are at the very bottom of my activity.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.me.proj.view.activities.MallActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:title=" "
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_mall_showcase_images"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffe5e5e5"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <include layout="@layout/info_card" />
        <include layout="@layout/photo_card" />
        <include layout="@layout/address_card" />
        <include layout="@layout/opening_hours_card" />
        <include layout="@layout/review_card" /> <!-- Button in this file has the problem-->


    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

review_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0.5dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="1dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_rating"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button_background"
            android:text="3.8"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_reviews_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_rating"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_rating"
            android:text="Based on 98 reviews"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_read_all_reviews"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Read All Reviews"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/txt_reviews_title"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txt_rating"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/txt_rating"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt_reviews_title"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_dummy1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt_read_all_reviews"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/divider"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_dummy1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_how_did_your_visit_go"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="How did your visit go?"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_tell_everyone_about_it"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tell everyone about it!"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>


<!--This got some problem-->
            <Button                                
                android:id="@+id/btn_add_review"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="Add Your Review"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_button_background"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        findViewById(R.id.btn_add_review).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You said "I have noticed that this behaviour is only shown by buttons that are at the very bottom of my activity." If you place the ** btn_add_review** button on the top of the layout **review_card** does it have the  same problem ?

Comment: No, button gets clicked when I place the review_card at the top, but then the buttons of the card that got placed at the bottom they have started to get that problem now which earlier wasn't there.

Comment: Whichever card that goes at the bottom looses focus and hence needs to be clicked twice. Just can't get my head around as to why it looses focus in the first place.

Comment: I have made an observation that when scrolling down to the **review_card** if I accidentally click on the **opening_hours_card** on the way which is placed just above the **review_card**, then the **review_card** gets the focus and the button on it gets clicked on the first attempt itself.

Comment: if you assign true to focusable and true to clickable true on the button what can we have ?

Comment: No, it still doesn't work, this is the most unusual problem I have ever came across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is actually a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37070828) in the `NestedScrollView` class for a while now.
I solved this issue my making some tweaks to the source code of the `NestedScrollView` class, as follows :-

```
public class NestedScrollView extends FrameLayout implements NestedScrollingParent, 
    NestedScrollingChild, ScrollingView { 
          ... 
       @Override 
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) { 
          switch (actionMasked) { 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: { 
                if (getChildCount() == 0) { 
                    return false; 
                } 
                //add this condition 
                if (!inChild((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY())) { 
                    return false; 
                } 
                if ((mIsBeingDragged = !mScroller.isFinished())) { 
                        final ViewParent parent = getParent(); 
                    if (parent != null) { 
                        parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); 
                    } 
                } 
               ... 
           } 
      } 

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        ...
        switch (action & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK) {
            ...
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                ...
                // replace this line:
                // mIsBeingDragged = !mScroller.isFinished();
                mIsBeingDragged = false;
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After doing this it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Code in my MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View view = findViewById(R.id.sub_layout);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do your stuff
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Code in my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="eflair.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/sub_layout"
        layout="@layout/sub_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Code in my sub_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't have any id by the name review_card, what should I assign review_card id to?

Comment: Create an id for **include layout**

Comment: <include   android:id="@+id/review_card" layout="@layout/mall_review_card" /> I did this yet it doesn't work.

Comment: And did this in code ->  findViewById(R.id.review_card).findViewById(R.id.btn_add_review).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MallActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

Comment: @ParagKadam, I have updated my answer. It works charm for me.

Comment: If there is only one or two <include layout> then it works for me too, but the problem starts when there are many such sub layouts and when you scroll down to the end then the layouts at the bottom are not focusable on when activity is loaded.